# Magento 2: Is it possible autoload Factories into PhpStorm?

Tags: magento2, phpstorm

I have loaded Magento 2 files and XML validation into PHPStorm which is very convenient. Is it also possible to do this (automatically) with factory classes and maybee other generated files? Since they are autogenerated in `/var/generation` PHPStorm does not recognize it by default and highligts them as "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is "not", out of the box magento2 just have some defined factories like `CatalogPriceFactory` (which have sense since are auto-generated) however you can add `var/generation` as source folder.

Personally I don't like to use it that way because you'll find some class definitions twice.

Anyway you shouldn't get any 'undefined' warning in PhpStorm for that looking, in my code I have that class that isn't showing any warn:

> Use Block:

[image]

> __construct Block

[image]

I'm not sure if I did some change in configuration to remove errors, i guess not, but I'm using the [Magento2 Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8024), that maybe is helping behind the scenes.