# How to get Magento 2 phpstorm namespace and code suggestions

Tags: magento2, phpstorm

Namespace suggestions: the code dir is marked as Sources Root but I don't get any. I just can't find any info about it. Looks like everyone in video tutorials just have it and nobody pays attention.

Code suggestions: I get them sometimes, but not always. I think it's because sometimes classes are not mapped and cannot be mapped by default php standards. Are there any extensions to help with this?

Comment: try also to add the var/generation folder as Sources Root, more details in this answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/99775/56025

Answer (score 0):

Some files in magento are auto generated plus you've got the composer installed files.

Therefore to get code hints on everything make sure you have an up-to-date vendor folder and generated folder in your local workspace.